# How to develop a function which returns the 'n'th number divisible only by primes (excluding primes)?

Tags: functions

To elaborate, I'd like to programmatically find numbers which can only be divisible by primes and themselves. I'd like to ensure primes are excluded from the output.

$n$ would be the input.
A few examples to clarify;

$n=1$ returns 4, $n=2$ returns 6,
$n=3$ returns 9, $n=4$ returns 10, $n=5$ returns 14, etc.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Turns out to be sequence A001358 in OEIS, thanks Raymond

Comment: Wouldn't $n=1$ return $4$?

Comment: @JohnDouma Yep, oops.

Comment: So you are looking for numbers of the form $p_1p_2$ for $p_1,p_2$ prime.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip not a mathematician, could you explain the subscript after $p$?

Comment: If you are interesed by [semiprimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) (as suggested by Grumpy Parsnip) then see [OEIS A251728](https://oeis.org/A251728) (your sequence) or perhaps [A001358](https://oeis.org/A001358).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni exactly what I was after, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped Chip and fine continuation,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni just grabbed that from the Wiki, thanks. Looks like the first one was the sequence I needed, TIL semiprimes are a thing